# Kentico v8.0.21 Contact Mapping Issue : Contacts not being mapped and stored on Form Submission

Tags: kentico

I am facing this issue in Kentico wherein a form submission on my website is not creating any contacts. The information is being recorded in the Forms section, but no contacts are being created. It says in the Kentico documentation (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Mapping+fields+to+contact+attributes) 
that:

"**When a new visitor arrives on the website for the first time, the system creates an anonymous contact without any data to represent them. If the user submits information on the site, for example during registration or by filling out a form, the system automatically transfers the entered values into the data of the matching contact.**"

However, this is not working. Can someone please help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have EMS license? Do you have on-line marketing enabled (Settings->On-line marketing)?

Comment: Yes, I do a license, and on-line marketing settings are enabled.

Comment: You have to provide more info. Are there any errors in the event log? Are there any relevant settings that differ from clean installation?